# Django View Aggregate Not Doing Calculation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a little division math in my view for an HTML display. For some reason I'm not getting a calculation with the below view.  I'm new to all this so any suggestions would be appreciated.
View

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import FloatField, F

class PatientListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView, Cast, FloatField):
    model = Patient
    template_name = 'patient_list.html'
    ind_treat_length = Patient.objects.annotate(treat_len=( F('cycle_length_days') / F('treatments_per_cycle')))

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )
```

The ind_treat_length annotation is what I have come up with for this.  My HTML template request is

```
{{ patient.treat_len }}
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the template variable is called `patient_list` (because it's not just one patient, it's a list of them).

Comment: From my reading I thought I understood that if I do this in the annotate line - Patient.objects.annotate(treat_len=(  
I would then call {{ patient.treat_len }}
in my html file.  I very well could be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing further reading and research I think the preferred method of doing calculations with Django is anywhere but the Views.py file. I moved the calculation over to the models.py file with the below method:

```
def treat_len(self):
    return self.cycle_length_days / self.treatments_per_cycle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a 'context_object_name' for your patient list. I don't know if it's still true in recent Django versions, but it used to be that the query results came with a generic name to access in the template (like 'object' or 'object_list'). 'context_object_name' lets you override this.

For more info, see the discussion of context_object_name here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Here's a similar stack overflow question/answer, but one wouldn't have known it if you don't know the name context_object_name:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959779/what-is-context-object-name-in-django-views